# Julia plot function array issues

Tags: plot, julia, gadfly

Having come from Matlab I am struggling to work out why the following does not work:

```
plot(x=rand(10),y=rand(10))
```

Produces a graph correctly.

```
x=rand(10)
y=rand(10)
plot(x,y)
```

produces error:

> ERROR: `plot` has no method matching plot(::Array(Float64,1),::Array(Float64,1))

I would be very grateful if someone coould explain to me why embeding the code within the plot line produces a result, but defining the variables beforehand results in an error. Logic says they should produce the same result.

I am using Julia v 0.3.1 and have loaded Gadfly as charting tool.

Comment: This gets at syntax as Toivo's answer indicates. But more generally, the plotting package you use may not have the same syntax you are familiar with. For example, Winston -- which is more MATLAB like -- uses plot(x,y) to plot the points connected by lines, as MATLAB would do and plot(x,y,"o") makes a scatter plot.  Whereas Gadfly uses plot(x=x, y=y, Geom.line) to make a line graph and plot(x=x, y=y) to make a scatter plot. Alternatively, PyPlot is more similar to MATLAB than Gadfly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the first case, you are using keyword argument syntax, not assigning to variables `x` and `y` (the meaning of `=` inside function calls is special). To get the same effect in the second case, you should use

```
x=rand(10)
y=rand(10)
plot(x=x,y=y)
```

which passes the value in the variable `x` in the keyword  argument `x` to `plot`, and the value in the variable `y` in the keyword  argument `y`.

Answer (score 0):

In case you didn't. Write this before your code:

```
using plots
plyplot()
```